# Conditional Expectation with linearity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Solving $E(X)$
$$=E(X-a+a)$$
(By linearity)
$$=E(X-a)+E(a)$$
$$=E(X-a)+E(a)$$
$$=E(X-a)+a$$

Does this hold for all probability distributions?

The place where this seems counter-intuitive to me is that, expected value for any distribution is $E(X|X>a)$ is $E(X-a|X>a)+a$. So there is an addition of $a$ to the expected irrespective of the distribution.

Where I am confused is that the difference in answer to $E(X)$ and $E(X-a)$ is dependent on the just $a$ not distribution.

Comment: If $a$ is a constant, then $\mathbb{E}[a\mid X>a]=a$.

Comment: @carmichael561 thanks, changed question now. Please check.

Comment: I think it's fine. You can always undo what you've done by noting that $\mathbb{E}[X-a|X>a]=\mathbb{E}[X|X>a]-a$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Where I am confused the answer to E(X) and E(X-a) is to dependent on the distribution as well and not just a.